# animate height when content is changed css3

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is There a way to animate the height of div when it's content was changed (by script and \ or css)?

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  }

#b {
  display:none;
  }

.wrapper.switch #a {
  display:none;
  }

.wrapper.switch #b {
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="a">
    Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
    </div>
  <div id="b">
    Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
    </div>
  
  <button onclick="document.querySelector('.wrapper').classList.toggle('switch');">swich</button>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [webkit-transition height for a div with a dynamic changing height based on content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588510/webkit-transition-height-for-a-div-with-a-dynamic-changing-height-based-on-conte)

Comment: Although the question might be similar I don't see why it would be a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this script will help you:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>stackoverflow</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        width: 350px;
        padding:20px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;

    }
  .box p{
        margin: 0;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
    .box p:first-child{
        padding-top: 0;
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Defining the function
    function animateHeight(){
        var newHeight = $(".box-inner").height();
        $(".box").animate({
            height: newHeight,
        }, 500);
    }
    $(".load-more").click(function(){
        // Setting the initial height of the box
        $(".box").height($(".box-inner").height());

        // Appending box with new content and animate the height
        var newContent = "<p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>";
        $(".box-inner").append(newContent);
        animateHeight();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="load-more">Switch</button>
<p>Height Changes Whenever you click</p>
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner">
        <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.. I asked about css3 solution only but thanks!

Comment: You've written by"script and \ or css". That's why I've provided the Script. But you're most welcome.. Enjoy...

Comment: The content was changed by script. I'm looking for pure css3 animation.