# Side Panel Nav - How to Collapse and Expand with Arrow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Was wondering how to accomplish the same effect as what is in Google Maps with the side panel navigation collapsing and expanding. When clicking the arrow the side panel nav expand and the arrow moves with it.  Please see screenshots picture attached.

collapsed

[image: collapsed]

expanded

[image: expanded]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapse_sidepanel

Answer (score 0):

w3schools has an easy-to-follow tutorial on a side-nav. [Check it out here!](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_sidebar.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a similar question that you need. you can take reference from
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11837673/11284301)

And for the arrow button, you can do some modification like:

Javascript

```
 var toggleBtn = element.children[0]
 if(toggleBtn.classList.contains("fa-caret-right")) {
  toggleBtn.classList.add("fa-caret-left");
  toggleBtn.classList.remove("fa-caret-right");
  } else {
  toggleBtn.classList.add("fa-caret-right");
  toggleBtn.classList.remove("fa-caret-left");
}
```

Html

```
<a onclick="growDiv(this)" id="more-button"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" ></i></a>
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/swetaunagar/pen/VwLmZNw)