# CSS3: Why is this transition not working, and how can I fix it?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

So, basically, I'm making navigation for a little project of mine and it's not working.

[Link to broken code](http://codus.tk/)

I've only put the code on the "Code" link, so just ignore the others.

The problem is: when you hover over the Code link, the "Test :3" text appears. Both the Code link and the "Test :3" are both in a table, each having their own TD. I used Javascript to change the "Test :3" TD to the right class when you mouse-over the parent element, that the table is in. All of this works perfectly fine, it's just that I want the width of the "Test :3" TD to have a transition. I've attempted to add this, but it just isn't working.

If anybody could take a look, I would greatly appreciate it. :)

Comment: its better to give your code here

Comment: did you try it in different browsers?

Comment: You aren't even specifying widths for it to animate between. Do you think it will just pull some out of thin air?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using tables in this situation. It is semantically incorrect.

Comment: Why put them in a table? If I understand you correctly you want the test:3 to "slide in" ?

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 I'm pretty sure that if you took a look at the bottom of the CSS file you'd see that innernav_closed and innernav_opened both have the width supplied. And what else was I supposed to use? If you're gonna answer, tell me what to do, not what not to do.

Comment: @btevfik I tried in Firfox, IE, and Chrome, all the latest versions.

Comment: @user1950929 Yes, I do want it's width to transition from 0 to full width (as wide as it's inner content). The width changes appropriately, but there is no transition. I used tables because everything else I could think of refused to stay on the same line as the previous element.

Comment: Ok I think it would be best to use lists or so. And for the transition: you have to change from width:0 to full width and not from `display:none` to `display:block` or so.

Comment: I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/73pgb/ maybe this could help.

Comment: @user1950929 Okay, I'll try it out.

Comment: @user1950929 So, that works, just one problem. How do I get it to animate to an automatic width?

Comment: it is usually not possible to use css transitions on properties with value `auto` , here is a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149419/
(very extensive and semantically not correct)

Answer (score 0):

CSS Transitions should be used for `<tr>` tag, not `<td>`