# How to create a menu that rolls down? CSS

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, css-selectors, transition

Example:

```
<div id="one">
    (content)
</div>
 <div id="two">
    <ul>............</ul>
  </div>
```

I want to create an effect that appears that #two is comming down from #one, I tried using transitions so when I :hover over #one so #two would appear to be coming down from #one but the content stayed there while only the background changed in size, I want the whole list to appear to be coming down from #one like in this website: http://merryweddings.com/

Comment: Does the height of your dropdown change?  If it does not and say it is a set 500PX high at all times, then this can be done with CSS only.  Otherwise it is extremely buggy as the only way to do it is to animate max-height, which makes it act a little funky.  If you don't have a set specific height on the dropdown then ur going to want to use javascript/jquery to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the size of the div that will pop up, you can do a simple transition on the 'height' property, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/BeDQr/

You also could use the transition on the 'max-height' property and set it to a very large value.

```
#two {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition-property: max-height;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper:hover #two {
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

But in this case, the end of the animation might be a bit abrupt.

Comment: is this crossbrowser?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use JQuery for this instead of pure CSS.

Check out this example : http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/

[This link](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/) also shows a lot of possible JQuery solutions.

Comment: No, thats not at all what im talking about, please refer to the website I pointed to

Comment: Ok, well I am pretty sure this could be done with a JQuery plugin but I don't know about only CSS.

Comment: It is possible via CSS only, but only if the height of the dropdown is fixed and does not change.  If the dropdown changes in height then javascript/jquery is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

See this link here: [How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto)

Also see the link in the first answer of the above link which is here: [Can you use CSS3 to transition from height:0 to the variable height of content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149419/can-you-use-css3-to-transition-from-height0-to-the-variable-height-of-content)

This, unfortunately is the only solution you have for a pure CSS method.  The second link shows a sort of workaround or a hack.  The first gives some further details.