# rolldown menu going upwards

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I would like to use css discussed here but making the menu roll up instead of down

[How to create a menu that rolls down? CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366988/how-to-create-a-menu-that-rolls-down-css/16367498#16367498)

Answer (score 0):

Just swap positionsof `#two` and `#one`.
Try this in that fiddle.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="two">
        <ul>
            <li>Menu1</li>
            <li>Menu2</li>
            <li>Menu3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="one">(content)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do this much the rest i leave to you http://jsfiddle.net/BeDQr/156/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="one">(content)</div>
<div id="two">
<ul>
<li>Menu1</li>
<li>Menu2</li>
<li>Menu3</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, * {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
margin-top:5em;
border: 1px solid black;
}
#two {
position:absolute;
height: 0em;
overflow: hidden;
transition-property: height;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper:hover #two {
height: 4em;
margin-top:-5em;
}
```